# Segmentation fault when reading from stack

Tags: c, stack

This is my first time creating stacks. I'm quite clear at what I must do, but am quite discouraged by the code not working.

It runs fine till I try to retrieve any data from the root, which immediately results in a segfault.

Here's my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct stackNode
{
    char letter;
    struct stackNode * next;    
};

int size=0;
int capacity=10;

struct stackNode * root=NULL;

void push(char data, struct stackNode * root)
{
    if(size==capacity)
    {
        printf("Error: Stack Overflow\n");
        return;
    }

    struct stackNode * new=(struct stackNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct stackNode *));
    new->letter=data;
    new->next=root;
    printf("%c,%u", new->letter, new->next);
    root=new;
    printf("%c,%u", new->letter, new->next);
    size++;
}

char pop(struct stackNode ** root)
{
    if(size==0)
    {
        printf("Error: Stack is Empty\n");
        return '\0';
    }

    printf("\npop*\n");

    char temp;
    printf("\n*\n");
    struct stackNode * tempad;
    printf("\n*\n");
    temp=(*root)->letter;
    printf("\n*\n");
    tempad=*root;
    printf("\n*\n");
    *root=(*root)->next;
    printf("\n*\n");
    free(tempad);
    printf("\n*\n");
    size--;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    push('c', root);
    push('v', root);
    push('n', root);

    printf("%c %c %c", pop(&root), pop(&root), pop(&root));
}
```

Here's the output:

```
pop*

*

*
Segmentation fault
```

Could someone point out the mistake?

Comment: [Added in relation to now-deleted comments about editing] You're new here William, and that's OK. You have the expectation that Stack Overflow is a chatroom or a forum, and it is neither. Stack Overflow Inc and the long-term community have struggled for years to make this clear to newcomers, and we find ourselves stuck in a daily Groundhog Day explaining this. The edits are not trivial given that technical writing is an expectation, but we understand every time a newcomer has this erroneous expectation.

Comment: The canonical advice about brevity [is probably this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions/260824).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is usage of unnecessary global variables which seem to be causing confusion. In `push`, the parameter is of type `struct stackNode *` yet it's being manipulated as if it referred to the global `root`. But `root = new` is purely local and has no impact on the global `root`. However, `size++` *does* impact the global scope. This corrupts the stack's logical state, and your error handler at the beginning of `pop` thinks that `size == 3` and doesn't complain. The function then dutifully dereferences `root`, crashing the program.

A correct stack class should not use global data. It should encapsulate all necessary state in structs. This makes it reusable, enabling creation of multiple stacks (a property I'd want in most classes I'm using).

A few other suggestions:

- Avoid [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) where possible. Prints are OK for temporary debugging purposes but should be completely separated from program logic otherwise.
- If you are planning on writing error handlers, print to `stderr` and avoid magic values like `return '\0';` that might be mistaken for actual node data.
- [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). This can suppress errors and is visually noisy.
- Hardcoding `capacity` feels pretty arbitrary. I'm not sure there's any point to having this (but if there is, add it to the struct). If there's too much metadata about the stack inside each node (ideally, there should be none), create a `Stack` struct to contain this metadata and point it to the actual `stackNode` chain.
- Another stack design point: `malloc`/`free` are slow. For character data, a simple array with a `top` pointer will be faster and simpler to implement. You can amortize allocation calls with periodic doubling the array when `top >= capacity` and contracting when `top < capacity / 2`.

Here's a quick re-write (without the suggestion for the `Stack` wrapper struct or the array):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stackNode {
    char letter;
    struct stackNode *next;
    int size;
};

void push(char data, struct stackNode **root) {
    struct stackNode *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->size = *root ? (*root)->size + 1 : 1;
    new->letter = data;
    new->next = *root;
    *root = new;
}

char pop(struct stackNode **root) {
    if (!*root || !(*root)->size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pop from empty stack\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char popped = (*root)->letter;
    struct stackNode *cull = *root;
    *root = (*root)->next;
    free(cull);
    return popped;
}

int main() {  
    struct stackNode *root = NULL;
    push('c', &root);
    push('v', &root);
    push('n', &root);

    while (root) {
        printf("%c ", pop(&root));
    }

    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really confusingly written code (i.e globals with the same name as variables in the local scope). I'm just going to rewrite it, untested and on mobile but should be fine. You can diff to see the issue(s). For one thing though you're setting local variable root to the newest allocation rather than global root.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct stackNode
{
    char letter;
    struct stackNode* prev;    
};

stackNode* kTailStack = NULL;

void push(char data)
{
    stackNode* p=(stackNode *)malloc(sizeof(stackNode));
    p->letter=data;
    p->prev=kTailStack;
    kTailStack = p;
}

char pop()
{
    stackNode* prev_tail = kTailStack;
    char n = 0;

    if (prev_tail != NULL)
    {
        n = prev_tail->letter;
        kTailStack = prev_tail->prev;
        free(prev_tail);
    }

    return n;
}

int main()
{
    push('c', kTailStack);
    push('v', kTailStack);
    push('n', kTailStack);

    printf("%c %c %c", pop(kTailStack), pop(kTailStack), pop(kTailStack));
}
```